# Verification errors vs validation errors

Tags: java, validation, testing, verification

I am a bit confused between Verification errors and validation errors. I understand that Validation errors could be more disastrous and checked against the product/software requirement specifications, whether we built the right product. 
ON the other hand verification means if we build the product in right way.

However, for example I am not really sure about verification errors. What kind of errors are verification errors. For example: error scenarios such as deadlocks inside the code because of possible wrong user i/ps OR wrong sequence of select and update operations would be treated as validation error OR as a verification error ?

Can someone gives few of the examples of verification errors ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Are we building the product right?" - this is verification question.
"Are we building the right product?" - this is validation question.
Giving that, deadlocks and other wrong programmatic problems they are verification errors. Obviously the bad code may lead to the bad product but root cause in the verification. The example of the validation error is some bad functionality like leak the mobile supporting or accessibility leak.

Comment: Thanks Eugene. So if I get it right any errors which are related to some bad design OR/and bad coding resulting into synchronization issues OR program crash, comes under verification errors, as it should have been verified properly against proper measures so that wrong/faulty code is not checked in and push into the production ? Also about the validation example that you gave. Do you mean memory leak ? I could not get the last sentence of your explanation

Comment: I mean missing accessibility features (sorry for the poor explanation). Please see the following [link](http://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/what-is-verification-and-validation) for more examples.

Answer (score 0):

Software verification pertains to confirming that the design meets requirements and is free of bugs.  Examples of verification errors include:

1. Requirement indicates that when input = A, output = B, but during functional test the software produces output = C
2. The software fails with run-time errors such as an integer overflow, divide by zero, out of bound array access, bad pointer access, or similar errors
3. During execution, software gets into a deadlock state (hangs)

A variety of development processes and tasks can be used to check that the design has been functionally tested and verified.  These include checking that the requirements are correct (i.e. not in conflict, are complete, etc.), confirming that the design (and software code) meet the requirements, checking that the design passes all of the functional tests, and a variety additional checks to confirm that the design is free of bugs (from both a functional and robustness perspective).

This link on [verification, validation, and test](https://www.mathworks.com/solutions/verification-validation.html) has additional detail.